# Excel- How to lock a formula used as a defined name?

Tags: vba, excel

So I created a "name" in my workbook to help me use a macro to run an advanced filter. Here is the formula:

```
=OFFSET('Property Data'!$A$6,,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5:$N$69),14)
```

This works fine except that I have a "delete" function written into the workbook that allows you to delete rows... including row 6. When row 6 is deleted the formula in this "name" changes to:

```
=OFFSET('Property Data'!#REF!,,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5:$N$69),14)
```

This obviously ruins the macro for the advanced filter and therefore users cannot edit existing entries in the database.

So I what I need to do is find a way to lock this formula so that it doesn't throw an error saying that the cell to be referenced has been deleted and it just uses the new row 6.

I have seen something like this done using brackets "{}" but I am not really sure how that works. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can _any_ row be deleted?  Eg if Row 1 is never deleted, modify your Offset to start from Row1 and offset to row 6 from there, using the currently unused row offset parameter

Comment: Alternatively construct your range reference using Indirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your Name formula ao it's not modified by the row deletion.

Two ways:

1. Anchor it to a row that will never be deleted, Eg if Row 1 is never deleted use

   ```
   =OFFSET('Property Data'!$A$1,5,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5:$N$69),1)
   ```
2. Use `INDIRECT` to specify the range

   ```
   =OFFSET(INDIRECT("'Property Data'!$A$6"),,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5:$N$69),14)
   ```

For both these (and your original) row deletion may also affect the `'Property Data'!$A$5:$N$69` part.  If this is not desirable use `INDIRECT` to specify that too.

Answer (score 0):

Reassign the formula every time someone deletes a row.

To detect a [deleted row](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/08/21/capture-deleted-rows/).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    glOldRows = Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count &lt; glOldRows Then
            MsgBox “Row deleted”
        End If

    glOldRows = Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Now you want to replace the `MsgBox` line with the reassigning.

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("FilterData").RefersTo = "=OFFSET('Property Data'!$A$6,,,COUNTA('Property Data'!$A$5:$N$69),14)"
```

So the end result should be this:

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: So I don't think the formula actually resides in a cell. I selected Name Manager>New...>Then I proceeded to right the formula into the reference box. I may be off base here but the actual name I gave it is FilterData... could I do something like FilterData = "=OFFSET('Property Data'!$A$6,,,COUNTA('Property'!$A$5:$N$69),14)"  ?

Comment: I never really did anything with Names but try this: 
Dim nm as Name Set nm = ThisWorkbook.Names("FilterData")  nm.RefersTo = "OFFSET.." I'm just guessing right now